# javascript, cookie, php and many more with ecommerce

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on a website which is e commerce website
I've done all but i'm not good with cookies 
so my client says that he want to know that the person who buy products from it how many times visited before by date , by time 
its open site so anyone can visit no session use, I'm totally confused with it huh

Comment: How can you be "not good" with cookies and you're developing websites? Anyway, what is your question? How to track how many times someone visited the website?

Comment: you are implementing an ecommerce site and you don't know about cookies, that sounds awful. anyhow check this function http://php.net/setcookie

Comment: I know setting cookie, destroy, getting values but not good with custom like cross browser cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you def need a cookie, maybe store the user's ip address and current date on that cookie:

```
//user details
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//set a cookie for 1 month                        
setcookie("users", $ip.','.$date, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
```

then every time the user logs in read that cookie, if it doesn't exist then set the cookie if it does exist add another value for the date.
When you want to know how many times a user visited your site just get all the date values from that cookie.